# Build a facebook app or web app?

Tags: facebook

I want to develop an online application and I am considering EITHER building a website with community features built in or building ONLY a facebook app. I was wondering if other people have had to make the same decision and what things I will need to consider.

The website I want to build will be an educational portal where people can make and take tests online

Comment: This is a very subjective question. Just my two cents: I personally wouldn't use such a Facebook app. Never ever. It doesn't appear serious enough, especially when it's about taking tests. Build your own website.

Comment: Btw. you should really add some **requirements** for your application, like which features you want to include. This makes it easier for people to objectively answer your question. I'd flag it as "too subjective" otherwise.

Comment: Zubair, are you trying to obtain data from Facebook by writing a Facebook app?

Comment: Well I guess its easier for people to recommend my app if it is a facebook app, is the main reason I want to know if facebook is a good option

Comment: What kind of tests would need a community with messages etc.? You mean like 'Which Harry Potter character are you?' as opposed to something academic or vocational?

Comment: @Rup: "Which Harry Potter character are you?" WTH you really made me laugh ;-D +1

Comment: Zubair, you can't replace a website with a Facebook app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I disagree with some of the other answers here. There is a huge difference between a) trying to advertise a new place on the web and b) trying to advertise a new functionality of an existing place. Even if this new website would offer a very tight integration with Facebook and some other social platforms. Keep in mind: facebook users really don't like to leave facebook, no matter what the reason would be. That's why the click-through rate for the advertisements is  so embarrassingly poor: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook#Company

That said you can of course always do both: build a website and offer the same functionality through a facebook app. However my opinion here is that if you're application only offers its users a single functionality, you'll be better off just doing the latter.

Answer (score 6):

What exactly is the advantage you expect by creating a Facebook-ONLY-App for that?

If it's only about taking tests you can still build a "normal" portal and include some of the Facebook-functionality through the JavaScript-SDK, like posting to the wall, Single-Sign-On, find your friends and so on. This way the user still has the choice if he wants to connect with Facebook or not. This way you also don't minimize your userbase to Facebook-users
(yeah I know, "everyone" has Facebook these days... ;) Still not everyone wants it to be connected to every single site he's using through Facebook)

Comment: The advantage of having a facebook app is that I don't have to duplicate all the community features that facebook provides for free, such as members messaging each other and things like that.

Comment: The problem you'll have is when users don't permit messages from non-friends - just as an example. Also I personally wouldn't want messages directly in my Facebook account from another appuser. I cannot think of any FB-app which does that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Considering this comment:

> Well I guess its easier for people to recommend my app if it is a facebook app, is the main reason I want to know if facebook is a good option – Zubair Mar 3 at 14:51

Build a website and then add the Facebook 'like' button. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#plugins

You should put a Twitter button as well:
http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you have to develop both. First develop you website. Although facebook is having millions of users But in my opinion you cannot implement every thing as freely as you can in your web application than facebook application. You should have a website and a page on facebook. You can integrate other facebook social plugins on your website to interact with facebook. 
From monitization point of it is easy for new users on website than application on facebook. Other reason website especially related to educational purposes have a huge click through rate which you cannot find on facebook application advertiser.

Answer (score 2):

What is the goal of the website?

If its to make money dont do a facebook app, you have far more control of your site by designing it entirely yourself.

If you want social networking features there are plenty of APIs you can tie in to which will provide you with functionality and allow you to link into facebook / twitter  etc.

A website would look more professional, it would allow you to gather statistics on unique hits, revisits etc, having your own database of users means you can gather information and market your site more specifically ( which users took which tests).

A website also allows you to monetize it by adding advertisement if that is your goal, and you can gain search engine rankings.

If you want to get publicity for your website you can use facebook by creating a group / page for the site and promoting it that way.

Also your own website wont leave you vulnerable to changes in Facebook, what if you put in all this work and in a year the terms change and a portion of your app is now in violation of the terms. What if you want to add X feature and facebook wont allow it?

Basically your site = 100% in your controll, thats a big advantage to you. With facebook you loose that advantage but maybe gain a little in being able to use more of their features. Personally id always go for my own site.

Answer (score 2):

You should go for the website first, then add the social elements in the website.

Like you can enable users to login using there facebook credentials. Like/share Button.

And later on, you can also go for the facebook app, when you want to shoot for much much more traffic. Therefore, whenever you think that you have figured out what exactly you want out of your application then only go for it, otherwise try your options with website. Because once your facebook app is up, you will get hell lot of traffic.

Let me know if you need help in creating facebook application or social elements enabled website. I have built an *Facebook Easy API* on top of all facebook features, which will enable you to easily access anything on facebook and meanwhile reducing your work effort.

Answer (score 2):

You first build it like web app and use Graph API and FBConnect to use Facebook functionalities. Then you need to create a facebook app version also because getting facebook traffic is also required. People from facebook most like come to facebook app then to another web. 
 You will not need to convert it to facebook app, it will be just less in width and it would be a facebook iframe app. as I some where read that facebook is depreciating fbml and iframe app is recommended.

So now you can make both things, as I think , test app can have flexible layout so that you don't need to change width for facebook iframe. So you can both things by doing one.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

i'm pretty sure many people will not agre with me, but **IMHO** you should *focus* on build a good `Web-App` that work well also on `Mobile-Phones`. keep it *simple, intuitive, responsive, lightweight, cross-browser and straight to the point.*

if your only concern is about "**recommend your app to other people**" make it `SEO` and `Multi-Language` too. google will do the rest.

<del>then if you want make your app bold, slowly and planty of useless stuffs start to add all the facebook widget you want.</del>

> PS: i'm also on facebook, twitter,
>   flickr, google etc etc, i'm also
>   sharing photos, links and usefull
>   stuffs, my google rss reader is full
>   of links with tons of nice things, well i
>   have never had a minute to look at it, when i need something i just start searching google

Answer (score 2):

I agree with most of the answers here—a native website is the way to go. Personally, I don't trust/like FB apps. Dunno what they do, and given the number of scammers out there and FB's lack of responsibility (IMO), I rarely if ever use an FB app.

Creating the website gives users choice about whether they want to share results/integrate with their FB wall/profile. Users don't like to be forced into something.

And in the spirit of adventure that is typical of SO, it's always more fun to build your own website than to build a template-based (sort of), boring and nearly irrelevant (drowning in a sea of other poorly made apps) FB app. But that's just my 2¢

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would do a hybrid. First, build your website, but integrate it with Facebook via connect. This way you can concentrate on building your value added services and let Facebook worry about the community.

I would also not ignore the Facebook app. Now, with iframes being fully supported on Facebook, you can adapt your existing site to work within Facebook with minimal effort, as long as you keep this requirement in mind when building your original application.